# how to "transmit" scroll animation from one uiscrollview to another

Tags: ios, uiscrollview, scroll

There are two uiscrollview A and B, when A is scrolling I want to stop it in sometime and the B scroll view keep going on the left scroll animation of A.

can anyone help me?

The B view is a uicollectionview , it is a sub view of A. when A scroll move up and B is going to out of the screen edge, I stop the A scroll and let the B going on scroll.

Because A has three subviews and everyone is different.(B is one of the views )

Comment: this is kind of interesting but, could you put diagrams?
anyway, first thing that came to mind is `–[ scrollViewWillEndDragging:withVelocity:targetContentOffset:]` method on UIScrollViewDelegate

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend you to check:
    gestureRecognizer:shouldRecognizeSimultaneouslyWithGestureRecognizer:
and you can also override the scrolling method and scroll the view A only when it's not in B or vice versa.